# Showing an error under a TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

Material design allows a text field to indicate an error via a small red label under the input box: https://material.io/components/text-fields (see screenshot below).

Is there a way to achieve this for a `TextField` field in Flutter? I expected this to be a property of either `TextField` or `TextEditingController`, but haven't found anything like it.

[image: Screenshot showing how a textfield with an error looks like]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is present in the decoration property in TextField, also you can style it using it's style property.

```
     TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorStyle: TextStyle(),
          errorText: 'Please enter something'
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You show errors based on the validation results which are returned by the validator function provided by TextFormField, You check for some conditions there and return an error message or null based on what you want to show and when, or if you don't want to show anything.

```
child: new TextFormField(
  autocorrect: false,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Error Message';
    }
    return null;
  },
  onSaved: (val) => //do something...,
  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Label*"),
),
```